# Open modules in Elixir?

Tags: elixir

Ruby has open classes, which are very handy (though reviled by some), and Elixir borrows heavily from Ruby, so I expected Elixir to allow me to reopen a module and add macros to it after having closed it, but this did not work in the way I tried it.  Is there some way to do this?  Is this feature available yet in Elixir?

To make this concrete, let's take an example from Chris McCord's Metaprogramming Elixir:

```
defmodule Math do
  defmacro say({:+, _, [lhs, rhs]}) do 
    quote do
      lhs = unquote(lhs)
      rhs = unquote(rhs)
      result = lhs + rhs
      IO.puts "#{lhs} plus #{rhs} is #{result}"
      result
    end
  end

  defmacro say({:*, _, [lhs, rhs]}) do 
    quote do
      lhs = unquote(lhs)
      rhs = unquote(rhs)
      result = lhs * rhs
      IO.puts "#{lhs} times #{rhs} is #{result}" 
      result
    end 
  end
end
```

If I then add a macro for subtraction

```
defmodule Math do
  defmacro say({:-, _, [lhs, rhs]}) do
    quote do
      lhs    = unquote(lhs)
      rhs    = unquote(rhs)
      result = lhs - rhs
      IO.puts "#{lhs} minus #{rhs} is #{result}"
      result
    end
  end
end
```

I get a warning that I'm redefining module Math, and the initially defined macros fail.  So obviously my approach is not the right one, but is there another approach that can accomplish the same goal?

Comment: You should not confuse the notion of a class with a module.  While they have some similarities, they're far from the same thing. For example, there's no such thing as private data in an Elixir module.

Comment: By the way, your example doesn't really use macro capabilities. It is recommended that you stick with functions whenever possible, which could easily be done here. Just use `def` instead of `defmacro` and remove all the `quote`s and `unquote`s.

Comment: Yes, true, but I hope you realize it's not exactly *my* example, it's Chris McCord's, and it's a "trivial" example just used for demonstration purposes.  Nevertheless your point is well taken.

Answer (score 19):

You cannot re-open a module. Since Elixir is a compiled language, the way from source code to an executable representation is one-way. The mechanisms that alter code, such as macros, are evaluated during compilation time. However, Elixir allows you to do hot code swapping, i. e. you can replace a compiled module during runtime.

I think this has some interesting implications. You get the ability to change the program at runtime – in practice, you control the source code and so you can swap out individual parts of a module without changing others. Still, I like the idea of having everything in one place. In Elixir, when you look at a module you know exactly what you've got*.

So if this question is only about a convenient development workflow – the closest you will come to Ruby's ability to add methods to a class is to save your module in a file and re-compile it from iex as you go.

---

* Strictly speaking, you might *not* know exactly what code is running by just looking at a module. When you are using protocols, you kind of need to look at all of the protocol implementations as well, which may be scattered throughout your codebase, or, even worse, they may be distributed across multiple applications.

Comment: Since you mentioned protocols, it is worth adding that places were people would monkey patch in Ruby to add extensions could be solved exactly with protocols. The documentation for defprotocol mentions for example a Blank protocol. A more in depth comparison can be found here: http://blog.plataformatec.com.br/2014/06/comparing-protocols-and-extensions-in-swift-and-elixir/

Comment: I understand protocols but I fail to see how this could be applied to the problem in the original question. It will still not allow you to add a named function to a method, or am I mistaken?

Comment: Patrick, you cannot extend an existing module but protocols are an extension mechanism, as it allows any developer to implement a pre-defined behaviour to any data type. I agree though it is a thin line to walk on and that your answer is more complete given the example in the question!

Comment: Although it would be great if protocols could dispatch based on entire patterns, not just Types. That would allow us to write different implementations for different structs, for example. Have you ever considered such a feature?