# Is there a way to add a function to an elixir module at compile time?

Tags: elixir

I am using elixir and following the advice from the
http://blog.plataformatec.com.br/2015/10/mocks-and-explicit-contracts/
blog post.

I have run into a problem of tracking which mock function corresponds to
which test. I added a mock module for the test environment for an api wrapper. As I add mock functions to the mock api module, I have found that I dont remember which functions were written to return results for which tests.

I have been trying to figure out a way to use a macro to define the mocked method near the test. I am also interested in this question as a learning exercise.

Below is how I would envision it to work:

```
defmodule SomeMockModule do
end

defmodule MockUtil do
  defmacro add_mock module, block do
    # <THE MISSING PIECE>
  end
end

defmodule Test do
  use ExUnit.Case
  require MockUtil

  MockUtil.add_mock SomeMockModule do
    def some_func do
      "mock value"
    end
  end

  test "The mock value is returned" do
    assert SomeMockModule.some_func == "mock value"
  end
end
```

This is similar to the question about open modules:
[Open modules in Elixir?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28291854/open-modules-in-elixir)
however I am wondering about how to do it at compile time not runtime.

I have looked around and I have not found anything that says it can or cannot be done at compile time.

In a way this is a fancy copy and paste :)

What I have tried so far:

1) The following works but seems rather messy. and it requires changes to the mock module. I am trying to figure out if there is a way to do it without the before compile.

```
defmodule MockUtil do
  defmacro register_function( _module, do: block )do
    Module.put_attribute Test, :func_attr, block
  end
end

defmodule Test do
  require MockUtil
  Module.register_attribute __MODULE__,
      :func_attr,
      accumulate: true, persist: false

  defmacro define_functions(_env) do
    @func_attr
  end

  MockUtil.register_function SomeMockModule do
    def foo_bar do
      IO.puts "Inside foo_bar."
    end
  end
end

defmodule SomeMockModule do
  @before_compile {Test, :define_functions}
end

SomeMockModule.foo_bar
```

2) I also tried, in the place of :

```
Module.eval_quoted module, block
```

however it throws an error:

```
could not call eval_quoted on module {:__aliases__, [counter: 0, line: 10], [:SomeMockModule]} because it was already compiled
```

I guess I am running into order of compile issues.

Is there a way to add a function to a module at compile time?

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried the `use` macro? You can read more about it [here](https://elixir-lang.org/getting-started/alias-require-and-import.html#use). If I understood your problem correctly, it seems like injecting functionality into your module with the `&__using__/1` callback is what you need.

EDIT:
I'm just not sure there is a way to add functions to a module at compile time without macros... We use the following macro:

```
defmacro define(name, value) do
  quote do
    def unquote(name), do: unquote(value)
  end
end
```

To define constants, maybe instead of `value` you could receive a `block`?

Comment: I have employed use in other code I have written. I will probably end up refactoring my first attempt and adding the use keyword to somewhat cleanup my first attempt. I am wondering if there is a more elegant approach to add a function to a module directly without the roundabout use of hooks in my first approach.

Comment: Yw. After fighting with the comments I decided it was easier to edit my answer.

Comment: The trick is I want to use a macro to define a function on another module than where the macro is called.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to figure out the following:

```
ExUnit.start

defmodule MockUtil do
  defmacro __using__(_opts) do
    quote do
      defmacro __using__(_env) do
        test_module = __MODULE__
        mock_module = __CALLER__.module
                      |> Atom.to_string
                      |> String.downcase
                      |> String.split(".")
                      |> tl
        name = "#{mock_module}_functions_attr" |> String.to_atom
        quote do
          unquote(test_module).unquote(name)()
        end
      end
    end
  end

  defmacro add_mock_function( module, do: block ) do
    mock_module = Macro.expand_once( module, __CALLER__)
                  |> Atom.to_string
                  |> String.downcase
                  |> String.split(".")
                  |> tl

    test_module = __CALLER__.module
    functions_attribute = "#{mock_module}_functions_attr" |> String.downcase |> String.to_atom

    first_time? = Module.get_attribute test_module, functions_attribute

    Module.register_attribute test_module,
        functions_attribute,
        accumulate: true, persist: false

    Module.put_attribute test_module, functions_attribute, block

    if first_time? == nil do
      ast = {:@, [], [{functions_attribute, [], test_module}]}
      name = "#{mock_module}_functions_attr" |> String.to_atom
      quote do
        defmacro unquote(name)(), do: unquote(ast)
      end
    end
  end
end

defmodule Test do
  use ExUnit.Case
  use MockUtil


  MockUtil.add_mock_function Mock do
    def foo do
      "Inside foo."
    end
  end

  test "Register function adds foo function" do
    assert  "Inside foo." == Mock.foo
  end

  MockUtil.add_mock_function Mock do
    def bar do
      "Inside bar."
    end
  end

  test "Register function adds bar function" do
    assert  "Inside bar." == Mock.bar
  end

  MockUtil.add_mock_function MockAgain do
    def baz do
      "Inside bar."
    end
  end

  test "Register function adds baz function" do
    assert  "Inside bar." == MockAgain.baz
  end
end

defmodule Mock do
  use Test
end

defmodule MockAgain do
  use Test
end
```

I was initially trying to avoid the calls to "use", but I need them so that the order of compilation is correct, and I think there no way to inject code into other modules anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Would you be able to provide a bit more information regarding "I have run into a problem of tracking which mock function corresponds to which test", because I think you may be overcomplicating this.

As per the article you linked, you'd use OTP application config to specify which module to use in which environment. In `prod`, you'd want to use the "real" HTTP client, for example.

```
# config/dev.exs
config :your_app, :module_to_mock, YourApp.Module.Sandbox

# config/test.exs
config :your_app, :module_to_mock, YourApp.Module.InMemory

# config/prod.exs
config :your_app, :module_to_mock, YourApp.Module.RealHTTP
```

Then, when you want to use the module, you'd simply grab it with

```
Application.get_env(:your_app, :module_to_mock)
```

In this example, the behaviour of the above modules would be along the lines of ...

1. `YourApp.Module.Sandbox` - Hit's the development sandbox of whatever API you're interacting with, if there is one at all. It's not uncommon to simply just use `YourApp.Module.InMemory` during development, too. Just depends on what you're using it for.
2. `YourApp.Module.InMemory` - All API interactions in this module would just return static, inline data. Such as a list of structs which represent what the real API would send back
3. `YourApp.Module.RealHTTP` - Real HTTP interaction.

As the article also states, each of the above modules would implement the same behaviour (ie. Elixir behaviour via `@behaviour`, this ensures each module implements the necessary functions so you know that your `InMemory` module will work just as reliably as your `RealHTTP` module.

I realise I've pretty much just regurgitated a bit of the article, but beyond that, I'm not really understanding your problem.

Comment: This is what I am doing. When I am writing functions in the InMemory module I have enough that I am losing track of which functions correspond to which tests. I use pattern matching to get different return values for the same function call.  I realized later I could use comments in the inmemory module to track. I just started wondering if there was a way to achieve similar syntax as same ruby mocking.

Comment: Sorry I still don't understand.. could you post an example of your `InMemory` module so that I can see what makes things complex enough to "lose track", and your tests around it, too, would be great.

Comment: As the code for work, I cant share it. we’re mocking an http library, and our application makes a lot of requests to multiple third party services, so we end up with 100's of lines of mocked responses

Comment: We get alot of different responses for the same service so we are unable to really break it up into different modules